# Autoformat word table in perl

Tags: perl, ms-word, win32ole

I have created a word document in perl with normal text and tables.
Now i want to format my table but i can't find the way to do this.
I know to put a format on my table i need to execute following command
`$table->AutoFormat(x);`  with x being e number from 0 to ....
But there are a lot of table styles. I want just a normal one (which is style 16) but i want to assign the border lines and vertical lines myself to create a table by my choosing. Does anyone knew the syntax for this one , or a documentation of the autoformat syntax so that i know which number is which table style

I know this is a question for documentation or tutorials but i searched a lot online and can't find any explanation about the autoformat syntax. And which numbers represet the border or the style . I hope some could help me out here.

Comment: You are being very secretive and have given almost no information. You need at least to say what module you are using and show enough code for us to reproduce the issue. If this is `Win32::Word::Writer` then I can't see any mention of an `AutoFormat` method in the documentation.

Comment: the module i'am using is WIN32::OLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at Microsoft's *Visual Basic* documentation for the
[Word object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/object-model-word-vba-reference).
The OLE interface is simple to understand from there

The page for `Table.AutoFormat` is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/table-autoformat-method-word)